# Using ng-href as a filter function

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-href

Is there anyway to pass a string through `ng-href` and achieve the same result as if it was the value of that directive?

e.g. 
    `{{ url | ng-href }}`

So that way the filter or pipe sanitizes any values and conforms the proper url scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear what you're trying to achieve. But if you wanted to be able to convert a string in the model into the `href` attribute on a `<a>` tag - you may use smth like this `$sce.trustAsUrl` ([angular site docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce))

> SCE assists in writing code in a way that (a) is secure by default and
>   (b) makes auditing for security vulnerabilities such as XSS,
>   clickjacking, etc. a lot easier.